# how to fix responsiveness in tailwind css

Tags: html, responsive-design, tailwind-css

I'm trying to make a form using the tailwind css and making it responsive, but when placing the classes used when in the resolution referring to the `MD:`  the
`md:rounded-br-md`  
class does not work, causing a failure in the layout.

---

follow the code below:

```
<div class="container mx-auto p-1">
  <div class="mt-4 grid md:grid-cols-3 lg:grid-cols-6">
    <input type="text" name="" class="col-span-3 rounded-t-md border-2 bg-gray-100 p-1 text-lg outline-none" placeholder="Digite aqui" id="" />
    <input type="date" name="" class="col-span-3 border-2 bg-gray-100 p-1 text-lg outline-none md:col-span-1 md:rounded-bl-md" id="" />
    <input type="button" class="col-span-3 rounded-b-md border-2 bg-gray-100 p-1 text-lg hover:bg-slate-300 active:bg-slate-400 md:col-span-2 md:rounded-br-md" value="Adicionar" />
  </div>
</div>
```

follow the code on [Tailwind Play](https://play.tailwindcss.com/QFynC4PU6r?size=790x720)

I tried using other tags described in the tailwind documentation but it didn't have the desired effect.

https://tailwindcss.com/docs/responsive-design

Comment: Please be aware that Stackoverflow requires questions to be completely in English. Please translate the non-english parts of your question: `problema com o MD: do tailwind css`, `segue o código no Tailwind Play`, or you may also post your question over at [Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/)

Comment: Note that the [<input>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-input-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Answer (score 0):

I might misunderstand the question but what I think you're trying to do is the following (Correct me if im wrong): The input button needs to have both bottom corners rounded on small devices, from medium up the input button only needs to have the right bottom corner rounded.

If this is the case, the issue is as follows: You're setting rounded bottom corners on small devices using `rounded-b-md`. Afterwards you're rounding the bottom right corner on medium devices again `md:rounded-br-md`. This only targets the right corner, not the left one, thus the left one stays rounded. To fix this you can simply remove the rounding on the bottom left corner with `md:rounded-bl-none`.

Note that since you're setting `rounded-b-md` first, the bottom corners stay rounded unless specified differently. (By doing `md:rounded-bl-none` for example). So you do not need to re-round the corner with `md:rounded-br-md`

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<div class="container mx-auto p-1">
  <div class="mt-4 grid md:grid-cols-3 lg:grid-cols-6">
    <input type="text" name="" class="col-span-3 rounded-t-md border-2 bg-gray-100 p-1 text-lg outline-none lg:rounded-tr-none lg:rounded-l-md" placeholder="Digite aqui" id="" />
    <input type="date" name="" class="col-span-3 border-2 bg-gray-100 p-1 text-lg outline-none md:col-span-1 md:rounded-bl-md lg:rounded-none" id="" />
    <input type="button" class="col-span-3 rounded-b-md border-2 bg-gray-100 p-1 text-lg hover:bg-slate-300 active:bg-slate-400 md:col-span-2 md:rounded-br-md md:rounded-bl-none lg:rounded-none lg:rounded-r-md" value="Adicionar" />
  </div>
</div>
```